# mount_afp on linux, user rights

Tags: linux, afp, fuse

I need to mount a remote filesystem on a linux box using the afp protocol. The linux box runs an old Debian 4.

I downloaded the source code of mount_afp, compiled it and installed it with all the required packages.

Then created /etc/fuse with the following command:

```
  mknod /dev/fuse c 10 229
```

(according to the instructions [here](http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/fuse/index.php?title=FAQ#What_do_I_do_if_.2Fdev.2Ffuse_does_not_exist.3F))

I can mount the remote filesystem as root by executing:

```
 mount_afp afp://USER:PASSWD@REMOTE_SERVER/FOLDER /mnt/MOUNTPOINT/
```

but the same command fails when run as normal user (of the local machine).

After reading here and there, I created a group `fuse`, and added my normal user `U` to the group `fuse`:

```
[prompt] groups U
U fuse
```

Then modified the group of /dev/fuse, that now has the following rights:

```
 0 crwxrwx--- 1 root fuse 10, 229 Feb  8 15:33 /dev/fuse
```

However, if the user `U` tries to mount the remote filesystem by using the same command as above, `U` gets the following error:

`Incorrect permissions on /dev/fuse, mode of device is 20770, uid/gid is 0/1007.  But your effective uid/gid is 1004/1004`

But the user `U` with uid 1004 has also gid `1007` (group fuse).

I might think the problem is related to real/effective/etc. ID, but I do not know how to proceed and could not find any clear instructions. Could you please help me?

---

There is also another problem. If I mount /mnt/MOUNTPOINT as root and run `ls -l /mnt`, I get:

```
  drwxrwxrwx 15 root root 466 Feb  8 16:34 MONTPOINT
```

If I run `ls -l /mnt` as normal user `U` I get:

```
 ? ?????????? ? ? ? ?            ? MOUNTPOINT
```

in fact when I try to `cd /mnt/MOUNTPOINT` I get:

```
 $-> cd /mnt/MOUNTPOINT
-sh: cd: /mnt/MOUNTPOINT: Not a directory
```

Then I unmount /mnt/MOUNTPOINT as root and run again `ls -l /mnt` as normal user `U` I get:

```
 0 drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 6 Feb  8 15:32 MOUNTPOINT/
```

---

After reading Frank's answer, I killed every shell/process running with privileges of user `U`. Still `U` cannot mount the remote filesystem, but the error message has changed. Now it is: "Login error: Authentication failed". The problem is not related to remote login/password since the same command works perfectly when run as `root` of the local machine.

---

Since I cannot get mount_afp to work with normal users, I decided to follow mgorven's suggestion. So I run the commands:

```
 mount_afp -o allow_other afp://USER:PASSWD@REMOTE_SERVER/FOLDER /mnt/MOUNTPOINT/
```

and

```
 mount_afp -o user=U afp://USER:PASSWD@REMOTE_SERVER/FOLDER /mnt/MOUNTPOINT/
```

The mount succeeds but user U cannot access the mount point. If `U` executes `ls -l` in `/mnt`

```
U@LOCAL_HOST [/mnt]
$-> ls -l
ls: cannot access MOUNT_POINT: Permission denied
total 0
? ?????????? ? ? ? ?            ? MOUNT_POINT
```

Is it so hard to have this utility working?

Answer (score 1):

Success for my single user setup came in the form of

- creating the group `fuse`
- adding `U` to the fuse group
- mounting with 
  `mount_afp -o user=U,group=fuse afp://USER:PASSWD@REMOTE_SERVER/FOLDER /mnt/MOUNTPOINT`

  - using the uid and guid was not working for me 
    `Unknown user 1000` 
    `Unknown group 108` 
    *these being the correct uids as retrieved from id U*

permissions were then set to 777 for the mounted directory and I was finally able to browse and play.

This doesn't solve the OPs question, but hopefully it's enough confirmation for some.

Comment: Did the `user` and `group` options get removed in newer MacOS versions?

Answer (score 0):

You probably didn't log out and in again after adding yourself to the `fuse` group. Group information is cached and so you need to do this after changing group memberships. Run `groups` after doing so to verify that `fuse` is listed.

By default FUSE mounts only allow access to the user who mounted them. If you want to allow other users to access them you need to add the `allow_other` mount option, so try this:

```
mount_afp -o allow_other
```

If that doesn't work you can set the ownership of the mount to your own user:

```
mount_afp -o user=1004,group=1004
```

Comment: I did log out and back in after adding the user to the `fuse` group. The problem concerns the user U not being able to mount the filesystem.

Comment: I would rather not assign the ownership of the mount point to a specific user since the linux server is used by several people who wish to mount the same remote filesystem.

Comment: Hi, since nothing was working, I tried to follow your suggestion. I modified the question. Do you have any idea why it keeps refusing to work?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.  Having added the username to the fuse group I logged out and back in (on ssh). But I still had the same problem. Then I rebooted the box.  It then worked fine after creating a mount point the user has access to.  So for me log out via ssh then log back in did not force reload of the groups, I guess you have to reboot or may be log out from all other shells (I am not sure if there were other shells I was log in on).

Comment: After reading your answer, I checked the number of running shells/processes for user `U` and found a plenty of. Killed every single process, now I have a different error: "Login error: Authentication failed". I updated the question.